# How to customize Material Input Text boxes to make it more compact design?

Tags: angular, material-ui

I am working on Angular app using Material UI v7. I feel the input controls are not compact. I want to have more compact text boxes. I know its possible to customize these and i have tried but not able to achieve this. Can some one help on this please

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve it. You have not shared your code, so I can't modify it, but if you want to customize it, you can do something like this.
This means you need add `mat-label` outside of the `mat-form-field` you have not

```html
 <div>
    <p>
      <mat-label>First Name </mat-label>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <input matInput />
      </mat-form-field>
    </p>

    <p>
      <mat-label>Last Name</mat-label>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <input matInput />
      </mat-form-field>
    </p>
  </div>
```

```css
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-outline-start {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  min-width: 30px !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-outline-end {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  min-width: 30px !important;
}
```

[Stackblitz Example V-6](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-input-custom-hagbm6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

[Stackblitz Example V-7](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-7-basic-tuyky2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

---

It affects some other CSS rules too, but update your component stylesheet with the related CSS variable:

```css
:host {
  --mdc-outlined-text-field-container-shape: 0px;
}
```

[Stackblitz Example V-17](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-17-file-upload-1fg3y7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Finput%2Finput.component.css)

Comment: Thank you @Rohit, how about the height of the control and no rounding corners

Comment: @SamK I have updated the solution and the live example as well.

Comment: I tried the same code in Material version 7 and the stylings are not getting applied.. Can you please help

Comment: @SamK I have updated with a v7-compatible live example as well, but I don't think there is any problem with the version. It might have an issue with your global style make sure you apply style in the correct order

Comment: i am so sorry Rohit, i meant Angular 17 and Standalone components. For some reasons the styling is not considered at all. Can you please help

Comment: @SamK I have updated my answer and added the live example of v17.